# Tutorial of building chat functionality with Swift using Layer?

Tags: ios, swift, layer

I'm looking for the Swift documentation for Layer since I'm looking for a quick way to integrate chat functionality into my app. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Partner Engineer at Layer. Layer is still working on Swift documentation for LayerKit for Swift, and we hope to have something available soon. I started building a port of Layer's Quick Start project in Swift. This project is incomplete and is very much a work in progress, but it will give you an idea of where to start with Layer and Swift: https://github.com/maju6406/QuickStartSwift

Comment: I want to use Layer with Swift too! Any updates here?

Comment: Hey Pratik, we're still working on official support, but it should be coming soon. We anticipant some change around WWDC so we want to make sure what we have works for all. We know some Swift apps that have shipped with Atlas so it's definitely possible.

Comment: Here are great ports of Layer projects using Swift:
https://github.com/kwkhaw/quick-start-ios-swift
https://github.com/kwkhaw/Layer-Parse-iOS-Swift-Example

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this on github? https://github.com/chatsecure

Comment: Yep, have seen that one. But I'm more into Layer or Parse, but I need a Swift tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikLydecker i want to use chat secure but parse is not working now so what other thing i can use